# Is there a level restriction on the Pokémon that can be used to battle Team Rocket?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have some friends who are able to use Pokémon who are 2000 CP+, but I have only been able to use my “Great League” battle combos.

Answer (score 12):

There's a bug when battling Team Go Rocket in Pokemon Go. If you have preset Great League or Ultra League teams, it'll prevent you from using stronger pokemon than would qualify for those leagues. You can fix the bug and use all your pokemon by clearing out your premade Great/Ultra League teams.

Edit: This bug has been fixed since this answer was written, so it should not be a problem anymore.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted my answer. I had no idea about the bug, and was posting based on my experience when it came to Team Rocket battles :) Give how the OP didn't specify their level or Pokemon, this does explain a better cause than mine

Comment: @Wondercricket, no worries. I only know about the bug and how to resolve it because I've been following several sources talking about it on Twitter.

Comment: Thank you! I went ahead and deleted my Great League groups and that worked out MUCH better!

Comment: @Kadima This bug has since been resolved, as detailed on [Niantic Support](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web&s=top-articles&f=known-issues&l=en)

Comment: @Wondercricket I've added an edit to show the issue has been resolved. Thanks!